# Adding different categories to multiple rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have three documents with hundreds of rows. I want to add them in a dataframe with different name categories. I am trying with the following code. But although I am able to combine documents in the dataframe I cannot attribute unique names to categories.

```
with open('fdi.txt') as g:
    fdi = g.read()
with open('gdp.txt') as g:
    gdp= g.read()
with open('gni.txt') as g:
    gni= g.read()    
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': fdi + gdp + gni, 
                      'categories': ['India', 'Israel', 'Fiji']}, index=[0])
```

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps it might be easier if you give examples of what `fdi`, etc. are (are these strings?)

Comment: Yes, these are text strings. These are text data uploaded from txt documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to answer your question without seeing some sample data of what fdi,gdp, and gni contains, and what your desired output would look like. But as you mention "rows" in the textiles and you have three categories I assume you want each category to belong to each file content.

So with assumption of textfiles containing rows of data, we can split them on the newline character `\n` the list of categories we can then lengthen based on the amount of rows the relevant file contains. E.G. `['India']*len(fdi.split('\n'))`

If above assumptions are correct you should be able to use below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': fdi.split('\n')+gdp.split('\n')+gni.split('\n'),
          'Categories':['India']*len(fdi.split('\n'))+
         ['Israel']*len(gdp.split('\n'))+
         ['Fiji']*len(gni.split('\n'))})
```

If this isn't what you were after, please add some sample content of the text files and desired output.

Comment: Thank you. This aligns with my data framework. I am sorry for not putting more details. But your answer corresponds to my data.